# angular 13 and twilio sync. TypeError variablename is not a constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, twilio, twilio-api

a note. When I was using angular 10 this was working fine. Only after I upgraded to angular 13 did this become a problem.

require is put in constructor as this is a Injectable service and I believe that requires it to be in the contstructor.

notice the code in my `TwilioSyncService`

```
export class TwilioSyncService{

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router){
    //@ts-ignore
    this.syncClientclass = require('twilio-sync');
  }
  syncClientclass;
  syncClient;
```

which is later used in code:

```
connect(token){
     this.syncClient = new this.syncClientclass(token);
     this.sendSyncClient(this.syncClient);
  }
```

the Twilio sync documentation says this is correct

```
var SyncClient = require('twilio-sync');
var syncClient = new SyncClient(token);
```

from the docs linked below.

https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/sync/releases/3.0.1/docs/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just installed the latest version of Twilio Sync and tried to require it like you did and I was unable to initialize the client too.

But, inspecting the object I got when I required it showed that it was just an object that contained all the classes. You're looking for the `Client` class in this case, so you need:

```
this.syncClientclass = require('twilio-sync').Client;
```

I think that your version of `twilio-sync` probably updated as you updated Angular. It looks like [this change](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sync/javascript/changelog#changes_1) came in the release of version 3.0.5 which described two changes that may have had an effect on this:

> - Default exports removed — they didn’t work in the previous versions either.
> - Fixed type resolution issues on Angular.

Comment: can you expand on how you found that? I know youre a twilio employee so maybe its unfair, but I clicked the link you put in and I couldn't find on my own that I need to use Client

Comment: To find how to fix it, I installed `twilio-sync`, opened a Node REPL and then tried to require and instantiate the client. Once I'd found I couldn't with the straight require, I printed the object out and saw the client class was within. Then I searched for the Sync Changelog, the Sync SDK isn't public, I'd normally look at GitHub, but I found [this page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sync/javascript/changelog) and then saw the text mentioning default exports.

Comment: You make a good point about me being an employee, I will ping someone to get the documentation updated so that this problem doesn't come up again.

Comment: Oh, it is updated. You were looking at the old version. The [3.0.6 (latest) docs have it right](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/sync/releases/3.0.6/docs/index.html).